# Unity Editor Scene is black

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a new Project in Unity and I always get this error in the unity console and my scene is just black

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mpw6u.png)

My version is `2019.4.0f1 personal`

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnityEditor.HostView.DeregisterSelectedPane (System.Boolean clearActualView, System.Boolean sendEvents) (at <af78ad00a40d4f61b82afc6cafb0a416>:0)
UnityEditor.HostView.SetActualViewInternal (UnityEditor.EditorWindow value, System.Boolean sendEvents) (at <af78ad00a40d4f61b82afc6cafb0a416>:0)
UnityEditor.HostView.set_actualView (UnityEditor.EditorWindow value) (at <af78ad00a40d4f61b82afc6cafb0a416>:0)
UnityEditor.DockArea.OnEnable () (at <af78ad00a40d4f61b82afc6cafb0a416>:0)
UnityEditorInternal.InternalEditorUtility:LoadSerializedFileAndForget(String)
UnityEditor.WindowLayout:LoadDefaultWindowPreferences()
```

I didn't do anything I just created this project

Comment: Basically, some `variable` is `null` and the code tries to access `variable.something`.

Comment: see https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NullReferenceException.html

Comment: I don't have any code

Comment: Did you install any assets?

Comment: no, I don't think so, I only started unity hub and created a new 3d project

Comment: Did you try to Restart Unity, Reboot the PC, delete everything except the `Assets` and `ProjectSettings` folder and re-open the project in Unity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it fails loading window preferences (LoadDefaultWindowPreferences). These are editor settings and the reason why you're seeing the error even on a completely new project.

Resetting the layout often solves this problem:
Window->Layouts->Revert Factory Settings.